# Graphviz labeljust can't align text to left

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to use `labeljust = l` to align the label to the left of the node `n`. However, it doesn't work.

```
digraph test {
    labeljust = l;
    node [shape = record]
    n [label="{aaa|bbbbbbb|ccc}"]
}
```

[image]

I hope it should be:

[image]

Use `\l` for each line is very inconvenient, so I want to use `labeljust`. How to get it to work? Many thanks!

Comment: From the graphviz` documentation (emphasis by me): _labeljust: Justification for **cluster labels**. If "r", the label is right-justified within bounding rectangle_. So it won't work with nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind, you can use [HTML-like-labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html)

What you want can implement as below:

```
digraph H {

  aHtmlTable [
   shape=plaintext
   color=blue      // The color of the border of the table
   label=<

     <table border="1" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
       <tr><td align="left">col 1</td></tr>
       <tr><td align="left">COL 2</td></tr>
     </table>

  >];

}
```

[image]