# How to place text next to a node?

Tags: graphviz, dot, neato

I am rendering a large-ish graph using Graphviz's `neato`.
All of the following takes place in this environment:

```
digraph G {
  graph [scale="1,0.7"]
```

Somewhere in there, I want to display a node that is just a colored circle, with a text next to it.

I am ok with placing two nodes (one for the circle, one with the label) side by side, but I somehow fail to left-align the text:

```
n1 [pos="1,-8!" style=filled shape=circle width=0.25 color=green1]
n2 [pos="1,-8!" label="the node label"]
```

Obviously, the label (`n2`) is centered on the node (`n1`) like this. Even though I intend to move the label slightly to the right in the final graph, let's keep it like this for demonstration purposes:

[image: centered node label]

Ultimately, this is what I'm trying to achive:

[image: properly aligned node label]

But for this output, I have to adjust the position of the label manually, in such a way that the center point of the label node is just at the right spot for the left edge of the text to be next to the circle - i.e. dependent on the label's length and thus rather unwiedly.

---

I have tried using the "left-align line break":

```
n1 [pos="1,-8!" style=filled shape=circle width=0.25 color=green1]
n2 [pos="1,-8!" label="the node label\l"]
```

The label is still centered.

---

I have also tried using the [`labeljust` attribute](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/labeljust/):

```
n1 [pos="1,-8!" style=filled shape=circle width=0.25 color=green1]
n2 [pos="1,-8!" label="the node label" labeljust=l]
```

The label is still centered.

---

Then, I have tried to align the text using a HTML-like label and the `align` attribute, as mentioned e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54102308/graphviz-labeljust-cant-align-text-to-left). As Creole's `<plain>` tag is not recognized by Graphviz, I have used `<font>` as the seemingly next best alternative of having *just* a wrapper tag on which to place the `align` attribute, without any further formatting:

```
n1 [pos="1,-8!" style=filled shape=circle width=0.25 color=green1]
n2 [pos="1,-8!" label=<<font align="left">the node label</font>>]
```

For this, Graphviz outputs a warning about an illegal attribute on the `<font>` tag and the text is still centered.

---

**How can I left-align my text, so it becomes easier to place the text node? Or is there another way altogether to put a text on the right-hand side of my node?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do what you ask.  **xlabel** should do what you ask, but you can't specify the label location (it seems to default to "near the northwest corner").
The alignment & justification efforts do not work, because they apply *inside* the node boundary, not *outside*

Here are three possible solutions:

```
digraph L{

n1 [pos="1,5!"    style=filled label="" shape=circle width=0.25 color=green1]
n2 [pos="2.0,5!" shape=plaintext width="1.2" label="the node label1" labeljust=l]

b [pos="1,1!" style=filled shape=circle fixedsize=true  height=.25 width=0.25 color=pink1
  label="                                   the node label4"]

d [pos="1,3!" style=filled shape=circle fixedsize=true  height=".25" width=".25" color=lightblue
  label=<
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
  <TR><TD width="138"></TD><TD>the node label6</TD></TR></table>> ]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Indeed, I tried `xlabel` and it yielded a very "unappealing" result for my purpose (some kind of a legend of different node types below the actual graph). Surprising that something like this is so hard in Graphviz, but thank you for the summary. I'll wait a bit before accepting in case there still are some other answers.